# Does system_profiler have private information I shouldn't send?

Tags: privacy, system-profiler

A support website is asking me to run `system_profiler` and send them the resulting report.  I looked at the output, and it is 62,654 lines long.  It has a lot of information in it.

Is any of it private information I should be concerned to hand over?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not something is "private" is completely subjective. An information might to you be extremely private and sensitive, while another person might think that it could just as well be public.

The output is in plain text - so you can read through it and determine for yourself whether you think it is private or not.

I think most ordinary, home users would find that it is not overly private or sensitive. If you're okay with the supporters knowing your name, username and what kinds of devices and programs you have - you are probably okay. Note that there's a (small) risk that some log output included could contain personal information.

Comment: I don't want to make a separate answer, but there is also the question of "trust". Even if there is some personal information buried in the 62,654 lines, does that matter if @dfrankow trusts the support website to handle the report appropriately.